# Android to Azure SQL Connection

Tags: android, azure, kotlin

I am having an issue trying to get Android and Azure SQL to talk.

```
class AzureDatabase(private val connectionString: String) {

    private var _connection: Connection? = null
    private val connection: Connection
        get() {
            if (_connection == null || _connection!!.isClosed) {
                _connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString)
            }
            return _connection!!
        }
```

I am in a kotlin multiplatform project and this works perfectly well on my Desktop application but creates

```
numMsgsRcvd:1 should be less than numMsgsSent:1
```

Based on my reading this is an open issue with the conscrypt library.

I tried using jTDS but the TLS version is out of date and nothing goes up to TLS1.2

What are people using to connect to this resource?

- What library version are you using?

Comment: Just making sure you've seen: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)